# SQLCMD variable in path

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I am working with some SQL-scripts that I want to be reusable, så I need to use some variables.

I have a bat script that run the sql script with sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -v PROJECT="<PROJECTNAME>" -i .\start.sql
```

In the start.sql script, I execute another sql script like this:

```
:r .\<PROJECTNAME>\init.sql
```

So I have hardcoded the value of the variable and that works perfectly. I want to use the variable itself, but I can not get that to work.

```
:r .\$(PROJECT)\init.sql
```

The last line here is what I thought would work. I have tested printed out the value in the variable PROJECT by doing this:

```
PRINT '$(PROJECT)'
```

That gives me the value of the variable.

Hope anyone can help me with using the variable to execue the script in the  folder.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
PRINT $(PROJECT) gived the following error message:The name "XXX" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

XXX = value of the variable.

Comment: What do you get when you use `PRINT $(PROJECT)` (no single quotes)?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? Did you get an error message? Or did something that was supposed to happen not happen? If so - what?

Comment: No, thats the thing, if I use :r .\$(PROJECT)\init.sql it just skip it without any messages. But switching $(PROJECT) to te variable value, it run the other script.

Comment: How do you know it has just skipped it? What did/didn't happen? This is a valid syntax you're using - I've done it myself in the past.

Comment: try putting the line "print  'hello!'; " right at the top of init.sql. Does it get printed? If not, do you have any other sqlcmd bits in init.sql? Perhaps something is interferring there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little experiment, as I know I've managed to get a syntax similar to this to work for me before now. I found that if I replicated what you had done, I got the following error:

> A fatal scripting error occurred.
>   Cannot find directory in the path specified for ":r" command.

If instead, I put the whole of the path into the variable - it works. So try changing your .sql file to this:

```
:r $(PROJECT_FILE_NAME)
```

and calling it from SQLCMD like this:

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -v PROJECT_FILE_NAME=".\<PROJECTNAME>\init.sql" -i .\start.sql
```

When I took this approach, it ran the file `init.sql` with no errors.

Comment: I just tried this as well and it works fine if I pass in a complete path in the variable, but I do not want to do that in this case. I found another solution on how I could concat variables in sqlcmd.

**:r ".\"$(PROJECT)"\register.sql"** this was the marked answer at this forum post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ce6b6277-340a-4900-814d-5714f74b411f/sqlcmd-variable-concatenation-behaviour-why-is-it-so?forum=sqltools